# Is there any way to join two queries without common columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Could anyone help me to join two tables without common columns?

I have two tables:

Tab1

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| K1 | a |
| K2 | b |

Tab2

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| K3 | c |
| K4 | d |
| K5 | e |

The result of select should be:

| Table1.Column1 | Table2.Column1 |
| --- | --- |
| K1 | K3 |
| K1 | K4 |
| K1 | K5 |
| K2 | K3 |
| K2 | K4 |
| K2 | K5 |

How do I do that?

Comment: This is called a CROSS JOIN.  I found this link thats what you need: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cross-join/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiddle -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ihJd4in3Tt7Fr8KZe6UvEC/0

```
select t1.column1, t2.column1  
from table1 as t1
cross join table2 as t2;
```